# Select columns that contain particular string/ID

Tags: r, select, dplyr, tidyr

I have a massive dataframe with nearly `300 columns`.
at the start of the column name, there is a code.

For example the column is:

`GSUP_02X Which supplier do you use for each of the following services? Telephone line rental`

OR another column name is:

`GSUP_03X Which supplier do you use for each of the following services? Fixed broadband`

```
GSUP_02X and GSUP_03X are codes.
```

So I want to select all columns that match a list of codes in a `vector`.

I have tried:

```
columns <- c("GSUP_02X","GSUP_03X")
consumer_brand_nps %>%
                      select(contains(columns))
```

But get the following error:

```
Error: is.string(match) is not TRUE
```

any other `tidyr` or `dplyr` solutions?

Comment: `select(data, matches("^GSUP_0[23]X"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `matches` after `paste`ing the 'columns' together

```
library(dplyr)

consumer_brand_nps %>%
                  select(matches(paste(columns, collapse="|")))
#     GSUP_02X   GSUP_03X
#1  -0.545880758 -1.3169081
#2   0.536585304  0.5982691
#3   0.419623149 -0.7622144
#4  -0.583627199 -1.4290903
#5   0.847460017  0.3322444
#6   0.266021979 -0.4690607
#7   0.444585270 -0.3349868
#8  -0.466495124  1.5362522
#9  -0.848370044  0.6099945
#10  0.002311942  0.5163357
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
consumer_brand_nps <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10*5), ncol=5, nrow=10,
              dimnames = list(NULL, c(columns, LETTERS[1:3]))))
```

Comment: ...it doesn't work. I get the error: `Unknown variables: `GSUP_02X`, `GSUP_03X``

Comment: the column name is: `GSUP_02X Which supplier do you use for each of the following services? Telephone line rental` so when I tried `consumer_brand_nps %>%
                      select(one_of(columns))``Unknown variables: `GSUP_02X`, `GSUP_03X`

Comment: @Shery Updated the post and it is working fine for me

Comment: super star! thanks for the nice example. works a charm!

Comment: just a last question, is there a way to check more than the `code` in the string? for example where code is `GSUP_02X` AND `contains("Virgin")`?

Comment: @Shery You may use a regex like `"GSUP_02X.*Virgin|Virgin.*GSUP_02X"`

Comment: dont wana take the p but do you have an example code? sorry for being pain

Answer (score 0):

Tested using data from @akrun.

```
consumer_brand_nps %>%
  select_(.dots = columns ) ## note the underscore
```